# How to get value from TextFormField on Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I would like to get input value from TextFormField.
And then I want to take it into Firebase.

If I have three TextFormField (last_name / first_name / birthday), how can I get these value and throw them into firebase?

[image]

- I had already connect and get values from firebase.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You need to use a `TextEditingController` for example:

```
TextEditingController lastNameController = TextEditingController();
TextEditingController firstNameController = TextEditingController();
TextEditingController birthdayController = TextEditingController();
```

Then inside the `TextFormField`:

```
child: TextFormField(
  controller: firstNameController,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
  labelText: "Enter First Name",
  enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
 ),
 // The validator receives the text that the user has entered.
  validator: (value) {
  if (value.isEmpty) {
    return 'Enter last Name';
   }
return null;
   },
),
```

Create 3 fields, assign each [`controller`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextFormField/controller.html) to each field. Then to access the value of each [`controller`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/TextEditingController-class.html), you need to use the [`text`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/TextEditingController/text.html) property:

```
 DatabaseReference dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("Users");
 dbRef.child("id").set({
        "firstName": firstNameController.text
      })
```

Check this:

https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/forms/retrieve-input

Answer (score 10):

There are 2 ways depending on your use-case:

1. `TextField` widget has a callback method `onChange` which you can use to get value once value is changed.
2. `TextField` has a property `controller`, to which you can asing `TextEditingController` instance and use it later on where you need it (for example on a button click) like this `textFieldController.text` which holds the current value of a textField